# Send notification if new post appears (getting data from rss)

Tags: ios, push-notification, rss

I'm building an rss reader. Now I want to implement a function which sends a notification to the user's screen if a new post appears (data comes from a rss feed). I thought a long time about it but don't really know how to solve it. 
Do you have any ideas how to do this?
Tanks for your help!

Comment: do you have a server, or are you talking about the client alone? Have you set up push notificiations?

Comment: No, I don't have a server and didn't set up push notifications.

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Thanks for your answer! DO you know a good tutorial which explains how to use superfeedr?